# C wait() does work

Tags: c

I was asked to simulate the Unix shell in C, and the part of code is following:

```
    int  pid, argc=0;
    should_wait=0;

    argc = makeargv(buffer,args);

    if(argc!=0)
    if(strcmp(args[argc-1],"&")==0){
            args[argc-1]=NULL;
            should_wait=1;
            }

    if(argc!=0)
    if((pid=fork())==0){
            execvp(args[0],&args[0]);
            exit(1);
    }

    if(should_wait){
            printf("parent here\n");
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Child complete\n");
    }
```

The parent process suppose to wait for the child if input arguments following by `&`
for example: parent wait child enter `ls &`, parent does not wait child enter `ls. However, the output is:

> osh>ls &  
> parent here
> Child complete
> osh>a.out
>   argv.c        myshell.c
> |

Comment: Actually, normally it's the opposite - the `&` at the end specifies that the job should run in background (i.e. the shell doesn't wait before giving you the prompt back).

Comment: @Ashik: he needs to wait for the child process to terminate, not for some amount of time. Delay has no place here.

Comment: Examine return value of `wait`! Also might be useful to check if `execvp` actually succeeded, and print error message instead of just `exit(1)` if it fails. Also, wouldn't hurt to check if `fork` fails, too.

Comment: Additionally, I would strongly suggest you use `{}` around every nested block. Too easy to make mistakes if you are "lazy" and leave it out, especially when you're learning. But at least indent your code properly.

Comment: any specific need to pass NULL to wait?

Comment: @shami and Ming, read man page of `wait`... Passing NULL is the first thing to change when there are problems, so you can get the status back from it and examine what's going on... Link: http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Answer (score -3):

AS from comments it is clear that exec replaces the memory of process with new image then you have no way to wait for child after exec. The reason for my rationale is that `execvp` does not return if it is successful. Instead use `system()` you can get status of child.  Just check the return value of the wait() it must be -1.

Comment: If exec detached, then how could you create a child process at all, other than clones of current process?

Comment: you dont call any exec it will be child :) you can perform different things in child also but if you want to execute new program then it will not be child of spawning process

Comment: @shami `exec` has nothing to do with parent/child relationships of processes. It loads a new program into the current process, and starts executing that program.

Comment: @shami Still wrong I think. Why can't you wait for the child process after it execs?

Comment: bcz exec does not return. My previous wrong understanding was also due to this same problem (of wait not waiting) which we faced in one of our class project.

Comment: How do you think `system` is implemented? It's "fork,exec,wait".

Comment: @Art I am afraid I dont know the internals of system but we solved the same problem with system() and passing reference in wait()

Comment: I am curious to know the reason of" wait() not waiting" other than that execvp does not return

Comment: @shami We don't know why `wait()` does not wait for the question code, because OP doesn't examine and print its return value, or the relevant pids.

Comment: Thank you all for answering my question. Actually, I have solved my problem by double "wait(NULL);" in the if(should_wait) function. However, I don't understand how does it works...

Comment: by double wait(NULL) means you used two times wait??

Comment: @Ming print return value of every `fork` call, and every `wait` call you do. That might help you understand what is happening (we don't know, not enough details in the question).